# It's possible to have a path with spaces in .npmrc on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I have an error calling npm config edit, it's like it's unable to find the notepad++ exe. I have come to the conclusion that the path specified in .npmrc can't contain spaces, and resolved pointing it to a portable version of notepad++ which is not installed under "Program Files". I was still wondering if there was a way to make it point to my original notepad++ installation, I had tried escaping or encodig the spaces with no success.

Comment: How are you setting your editor, i.e. what command are you using?. Perhaps you can edit your question to show us what command(s) you have tried. Have you tried setting your editor using the command: `npm set editor "<path>" -g` - whereby the `<path>` part is the actual path to the _notepad++_ you want to use and the path itself is wrapped in double quotes `"..."`?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately npm will split on all Spaces, no matter how you escape them.
[Source Code NPM cli edit - Line 59:](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/lib/commands/edit.js#L59) (Accessed: 2023-02-20)

```js
const [bin, ...spawnArgs] = this.npm.config.get('editor').split(/\s+/)
```

Therefore you have to set an Editor File path without any Spaces.

**Assumption for the Examples**

- **VS Code** is used in the Examples. Exchange the VS Code File Path with your favorite Editor.
- **NPM User Profile** is updated, if you like the **Global Profile** use `-g` with every npm command.

**Example 1 - Add Editor Directory to Path**

This will only set the PATH temporary. To set permanently on Windows 10 do `Start - Edit environment variables for your account` and add Path.

**Edit**: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin" ist the Path VS Code will set will installing.

```
> set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin"

> npm config set editor code.cmd

> npm config edit
```

**Example 2 - Use DOS Short Name**

Get the DOS Short name for the File and use this as parameter for `npm config set editor`. The Short Name varies from System to System. If VS Code is uninstalled and reinstalled, the Path might change.

- for %I in () do ...
  Process every File in `<filelist>`
- echo %~sI
  Print Filename in Short Format

```
> for %I in ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe") do echo %~sI
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~3\Code.exe

> npm config set editor C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~3\Code.exe
```